# Instantly update data in another tab using Realm React-Native

Tags: react-native, realm, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I,m Working on a react-native app using BottomTabNavigator. The user can bookmark an article and I save to Realm DB. The problem is that I want the **bookmarked article to appear instantly in other tab**, but I'm only seeing the bookmarked articles only after restarting the app.
Please let me know **how can I fetch data as soon as an item is added to RealmDB.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register a listener. Check out the section on [notifications](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was frustrated trying to use lifecycle-event listener(which wasn't working, God knows why?
).
Trying this notification approach yielded the result with only few lines of code.